# unable to run Exchange Powershell through vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, powershell, exchange-server

So I'm going round in circles trying to get this to work, I've been trying for two days and I just can't figure it out.

I have the following vb function that takes a created powershell script, and should run it in powershell. Everything works fine, until the point at which the command pipeline is invoked. At this point, no commands run.

As you can see, I have tried to add the Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 snapin to the runspace, it didn't like that at all stating something along the lines of the snapin didnt exist (which it does), and also when I run the code as shown, no commands are recognised as valid. I even added the specific command "Add-PSSnapin" to try and load any Exchange snapins, but it states that "Add-PSSnapin" is not recognised as a valid command.

If I pause the program just before the commands are involked, I can see every command within the pipeline, in the correct format. If I copy and paste the command text in the pipeline directly into a powershell window, it runs fine.

My code is below, any suggestions welcome.

edit: I have also tried adding the line "Add-PSSnapin *Ex*" (with an asterisk each side of Ex - I cant figure the formatting out on this, sorry)

to try and load the Exchange PS Snapins as the first thing the script would run (opposed to setting this up in the runspace) but no luck

```
Private Function scriptRunner(ByVal scripttorun As String) As String

    Dim initial As InitialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim lineFromScript As String = ""
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(tempScript)

    Dim rsConfig As RunspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create()
    Dim snapInException As New PSSnapInException

    Dim strUserName As String = "DOMAIN\USER"
    Dim strPassword As String = "PASSWORD"
    Dim SecuredPSWD As New System.Security.SecureString()
    For Each character As Char In strPassword
        SecuredPSWD.AppendChar(character)
    Next

    Dim wsmConnectionInfo As WSManConnectionInfo
    Dim strSystemURI As String = "http://SERVER.DOMAIN/powershell?serializationLevel=Full"
    Dim strShellURI As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange"
    Dim powerShellCredentials As PSCredential = New PSCredential(strUserName, SecuredPSWD)
    wsmConnectionInfo = New WSManConnectionInfo(New Uri(strSystemURI), strShellURI, powerShellCredentials)
    Dim runspace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(wsmConnectionInfo)
    Runspace.Open()
    ' runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", snapInException)


    Dim pipeLine As Pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline()

    Dim command As Command = New Command("")
    ' TEST >> pipeLine.Commands.Add("Add-PSSnapin *Ex*")
    Do While reader.Peek() <> -1
        lineFromScript = Nothing
        lineFromScript = reader.ReadLine()
        pipeLine.Commands.Add(lineFromScript)
        'command.Parameters.Add(lineFromScript)
        'pipeLine.Commands.Add(command)

    Loop

    '' Run the contents of the pipeline
    Dim psObjCollection As Collection(Of PSObject) = pipeLine.Invoke()

    runspace.Close()
    runspace.Dispose()

    Return ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around the problem rather than fixing it.

I moved the script code into the vb.net application, and wrote each line to a file, i.e.

```
        writer.WriteLine("Add-PSSnapin *Ex*")
```

Then I loaded the script through PowerShell as an application;

```
            Dim exeStartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        Dim exeStart As New System.Diagnostics.Process

        exeStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe")
        exeStartInfo.Arguments = ("-command work\scriptbuilder.ps1")
        exeStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\ExchangeManager\"
        exeStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        exeStart.StartInfo = exeStartInfo
        exeStart.Start()
        exeStart.Close()
```

Not ideal but it got the job done.